# my object cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java

right now I'm studying Java but I have a problem on 
`if ( (maPartie.getEchiquier().getPiecePosition(pos).getPosition())==Partie.posPieceAttaquanteEchec) )`  where the `posPieceAttaquanteEchec` cannot be resolved or is not in field and I don't find where the problem is..

Thanks to help me I'm a beginning and I ask only to learn ;)

```
    while(maPartie.estEchec(joueurActuel)) {
        if (maPartie.getEchiquier().getPiecePosition(Partie.posPieceAttaquanteEchec) instanceof Roi)

                            //
                            //
    do {
        String str;
        do {    
        System.out.println(joueurActuel.getNom()+ " - Piece à déplacer : ");
        str = whichpiece.nextLine();
        } while (str.length() == 0);

        if (str.equals("1")) {
        Coup petitRoque = new Coup(1);
        maPartie.jouerCoup(joueurActuel, petitRoque);
            roque = true;
            break;
        } else if (str.equals("2")) {

    Coup grandRoque = new Coup(2);
    maPartie.jouerCoup(joueurActuel, grandRoque);
            roque = true;
            break;
    }

    p = maPartie.getEchiquier().getPiecePosition(new Position(str));
        if (p != null) {

        Couleur couleur = joueurActuel.getCouleurPieces();


        List<Position> listPos = p.positionsAtteignableEchiquier(maPartie.getEchiquier());
         for (Position pos : listPos) {
            if ( (maPartie.getEchiquier().getPiecePosition(pos).getPosition()) == (Partie.posPieceAttaquanteEchec) ) {

System.out.println("La piece choisie est : " + p + " positions possibles --> " + p.positionsAtteignableEchiquier(maPartie.getEchiquier()));
        echec = true;
        String str2;
        do {
         System.out.println(joueurActuel.getNom() + " - Déplacement à faire : ");
         str2 = whichpiece.nextLine();
        } while (str2.length() == 0);

        Coup coupPiece = new Coup(p, new Position(str2));
       maPartie.jouerCoup(joueurActuel, coupPiece);             

         break;
        }
        else {

            }
        }
        }
        } while(p == null);
        }
```

Comment: It would be super fantastic if you could format your code and provide the exception stack trace

Comment: @damo It sounds like a compiler error.

Comment: Please post the declaration for `Partie` and for `posPieceAttaquanteEchec`.

Comment: Well, it's pretty clear.  whatever `Partie` is, it doesn't have a member called: `posPieceAttaquanteEchec`

Comment: Yes, what Code-Guru said. It is likely `posPieceAttaquanteEchec` is not a static variable.

Comment: @Teeg are you certain that `Partie` is the name of a class?

Comment: @Code-Guru Ah, you're right...it would be super fantastic if I actually read the question!

Comment: @SamIam You're right, it could very well not be. Impossible to make either determination without seeing whatever `Partie` is.

Comment: sorry about the edit.  the user 250XXXXs all look the same to me

Comment: You should definitely format your code and provide the actual exception message.

Answer (score 1):

Some more code would be helpful (and I don't know French?). But basically you are trying to access a variable that is not defined anywhere. You are referencing posPieceAttaquanteEchec statically, which means it is declared with the static keyword, like this:

```
class Partie
{
   static private int posPieceAttaquanteEchec;
}
```

An object version of the variable would be defined as such:

```
class Partie
{
   private int posPieceAttaquanteEchec;
}
```

If you want to reference an object version of the variable, you would use:

```
maPartie.posPieceAttaquanteEchec
```